# Google Sheets - conditional formatting between cells for a whole column?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight cells in column B that are different from cell on the same row in column A

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC |
| DEF | GHI |
| GHI | GHI |

`GHI` in column B, in the `DEF`-row should be highlighted.

The table contains hundreds of rows.

I have read several guides but they all seem to be either based on comparing a single cell with a whole column or you have to manually adjust the formula (something like `=EQ(C15;D15)`) for each row.

For basically everything else you any modern spreadsheet software is "smart" when you apply the same operation for all values in a column, e.g., if the formula in C1 is `=A1+B1` and you copy it to C2 the formula changes to `=A2+B2`. I am looking for something similar for conditional formatting.

Comment: I recommend you find few tutorials on learning the basics of Sheets.  You are  speaking about relative vs absolute references, and the conditional formatting rule for `B1` would be `=A1` and the range would be `B:B`.  **[`Conditional Formatting Rule example`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkCKH.gif)**

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150342/discussion-on-question-by-d-b-google-sheets-conditional-formatting-between-cel); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.